# C# Coding Best Practice

Tags: c#

I'm currently doing work which requires me to convert VB.Net code to C#.
I've been using the "Builder Pattern" primarily and this has me converting many functions that are one single call of a function ie. SomeFunction(var1,var2,var3) into:

```
Dim Director As New SomeDirector
With Director
.SomeProperty = SomeValue
.SomeProperty2 = SomeValue2
End With
```

My concern is that this creates 5-6 lines of code rather than one single line. Is there a way for me to do this in a more concise way or is it better to have the 5-6 lines of code?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get it. That code is not a function call and it is not c#. Regardless, best practice questions are better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would actually recommend softwareengineering over codereview in this circumstance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One neat way to write that is with a constructor in the SomeDirector class:

```
public SomeDirector(int value1, int value2)
{
    this.SomeProperty = value1;
    this.SomeProperty2 = value2;
}
```

then your code sample becomes:

```
var director = new SomeDirector(someValue, someValue2);
```

The idea here is that while the constructor looks a bit long-winded, it's tucked away in the class and the code that calls it is nice and concise (and you can't forget an important property).

In case you wondered, there's no C# equivalent of VB's `with` keyword.

Comment: In the context they are using it, VB's `With` is equivalent to C#'s object initialisation.

Comment: Thanks Robin I will try this out right now and let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you can do something similar in C# with object initialisation:

```
var Director = new SomeDirector { SomeProperty = SomeValue, SomeProperty2 = SomeValue2 };
```

This does not require you to write an explicit constructor.

Answer (score 0):

More of a general answer to your question:
In theory it doesnt matter how many lines of code you have, only how much resources it costs to execute. But best practices are also about human readability so it really depends on the situation. Do you need to optimize for performance or further development. This is something that in most cases you as a developer will know better than anyone else who dont have the full insight.